# Jquery slimscroll doesn't hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

I am using jquery slimscroll plugin and I have a problem because it is shown even when there is no need, and after I move mouse, or tap on the page it hides (this happen when I navigate to the page where I use it). Is there any work around for this - I tried changing the plugin code, but the problem is it using page dimensions to determine visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue and it's hard to believe what I found as a solution. Ready? Just remove the border on the container where you have applied the slimscroll. That fixed it.

I haven't found it necessary to look into the code but I am sure there's an easy fix for this.

Comment: fixed, but what about if I need a border on the container?

Comment: It's true that there's an issue in the plugin if the parent element has a border which causes the scrollbar to always be displayed. I've logged an issue on the project's GitHub page, although the creator doesn't seem to take much of an interest in the issues raised, unfortunately. As @AndrewTobilko says, this solution is a poor workaround if you actually want your parent element to have a border!